# Do agni's immortality contradicts gita 2:27?

Tags: vedas, gods, agni, contradiction

RV 3.26.7

> अग्निरस्मि जन्मना जातवेदाः घृतं मे चक्षुरमृतं म आसन् ।
> अर्कस्त्रिधातू रजसो विमानो अजस्रो घर्मो हविरस्मि नाम ॥
>
> “I am Agni, **omniscient by birth**, Light is my eye and Immortality is my mouth. I am the three-fold Light that measures the universe. **I am both immortal energy and matter**.” [SOURCE](https://goldenreedhiranyayavetasa.blogspot.com/)

In this verse Agni is saying that he is Omniscience by birth. And also he is saying that he is immortal.

But this contradicts Gita 2:27 :

> BG 2.27: **Death is certain for one who has been born**, and rebirth is inevitable for one who has died. Therefore, you should not lament over the inevitable.

It say the one who is born he/she will die.

MY QUESTION : In RV 3.26.7 Agni is saying he is immortal and Omniscience **by birth** but in the gita anyone who is born is certain to dies.Angi's immortality contradicts gita 2:27.
What is the solution to this apparent contradiction?

Comment: OMG - tough to explain this away @darkknight

Comment: @SK can you explain, what do you mean by "*OMG - tough to explain this away*"

Comment: seems to be an outright contradiction @darkknight

Comment: You are conflating two different ideas. In the Rg Veda, Agni is being identified with Brahman whose identification is being described as a manifested being. The use of the word 'birth' shouldn't be taken literally. The verse from the Gita refers to ordinary jivas. Recommend reading Gita Chapter 10.

Comment: In the Uddhava Gita Krishna says (VI.1) - "The soul is described as bound or free from the point of view of My Gunas, but it is not so in reality. And since the Gunas are the creation of Maya, there is, in My opinion, neither bondage nor liberation."

Comment: Considering [this](http://www.vedakosh.com/rig-veda/mandal-3/sukta-026/mantra-rig-03-026-007) and [this](https://archive.org/details/RigvedInHindi/page/n389/mode/2up) the last line should roughly translate to: Like that sun who is always bright, like that Homa and the components of it, I am that (Agni).

Comment: @Proxy I think this is a good translation. It's an Indian translation https://goldenreed-hiranyayavetasa.blogspot.com/

Comment: Yes, might be, Although English translation often mislead. By the way I am not an expert, shared what I found. Let's see if an answer comes up.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda it is not mentioned in the verse that Agni is identified as Brahman

Comment: @DarkKnight - what you're trying to do is like trying to understand Einstein's theory of relativity, by saying 'E=MC^2' does not say what E , M , C means. Of course, the formula will not have the meaning, you have to read the papers, commentary etc. Similarly, you can't learn Vedas by reading a few English translated lines and expect to know the meaning

Comment: Birth for a jiva vs ajiva mean different things. Birth and death of non living matter would indicate energy transforms.

Comment: Agni, Vayu, Varun, Indra, Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesha etc., are universal 33 standard positions just like every human has 206 bones, 2 eyes, 2 legs etc.,. The story of Agni encountering formless Brahman and getting defeated is mentioned in Kena Upanishad. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kena-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145056.html Of course Devas(enlightened beings) live very long compared to common humans and have lot of knowledge and powers and therefore appear as master God to humans just like humans(70-80 years) live very long compared to their pets which live for 4-5 years.

Comment: I am Brahman,therefore it became all.Whoever among gods had this enlightenment,also became That.It is same with sages & men.Whoever knows self as “I am Brahman,”becomes all this universe.Even gods cannot prevail against him,for he becomes their Ātma.Now, if a man worships another god,thinking: “He is one and I am another,” he doesn't know.He is like an animal to gods.As many animals serve a man, so does each man serve gods.Even if one animal is taken away,it causes anguish;how much more so when many are taken away?Therefore it is not pleasing to gods that men should know this- Brihad. Up 1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agni is immortal in the same way that Krishna, even though born of Devaki and Vasudeva, is immortal. Both Agni and Krishna are saguNa brahman and are hence immortal, even though they have births and even apparent deaths (as in the case of Krishna). Here, immortality means - being free from birth-death cycle that arises due to karma. SaguNa brahman, being free from karma eternally, can still choose to manifest himself or herself as various forms like Agni, Krishna etc.

BG 2.27 is applicable to bonded jiva-s only, who are affected by ignorance. In the Rig Veda verse, Agni is called as omniscient, and Agni is hence beyond ignorance. As such BG 2.27 is not applicable to Agni.