# What are some similar verses to Gita 2:26

Tags: death, life, gita

> BG 2.27: Death is certain for one who has been born, and rebirth is inevitable for one who has died. Therefore, you should not lament over the inevitable.

Can you give some similar verses from the vedas. That says "*Death is certain for one who has been born*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mandukya Karika has a similar verse -

> Ātman, in regard to its birth, death, going and coming (i.e.,
> transmigration) and its existing in different bodies, is not
> dissimilar to the Ākāśa (Mandukya Karika 3.9)

Shankaracharya comments "The point which has been just stated is again thus developed:—Birth, death, etc., of the Ātman as seen in all bodies is like the creation, destruction, coming, going and existence of the Ghaṭākāśa"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I be honest I need a verse to support my [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/45762/22556) question. Can you provide me any verse that support my this question

Comment: I don't know what's problem with that topic. Agni is personified as Brahman in that verse if you read Ram Abloh Blog clearly. Gita is speaking about Atman when it accepts various bodies based on Karma. @DarkKnight

Comment: I am Agni amongst the Vasus and Meru amongst the mountains.(Gita 10.23)

Comment: my problem is with "**by birth**" thing. The verse doesn't say he is personified as Brahman. It is just an interpretation(commentary).

Comment: Again @DarkKnight Lets assume birth is the thing which you speak of. Then Gita is saying I am Agni which is contradicting your logic. It has to be metaphoric meaning

Answer (score 4):

> Can you give some similar verses from the vedas

Assuming upanishads can be considered as part of vedas -

A similar verse is found in [Katha upanishad 2.1.10 second half](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/katha-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145231.html)

> mṛtyoḥ sa mṛtyumāpnoti ya iha nāneva paśyati ||

(Translating and interpreting according to advaita.)

> He who sees multiplicity here, **goes from death to death.**

Explaining this Sankaracharya says -

> This being so, he who here deluded by ignorance, which consists in seeing difference by the nature of the conditions sees in the Brahman which is one, a variety, thinking thus ‘I am other than the highest Brahman and the highest Brahman is other than I’, **goes from death to death, i.e., is again born and dies**; so, one should not see thus.

The meaning is that a person who does not know brahman, keeps taking birth and dying again and again.

Comment: Not commetary but the verses it self. It should be clear. Like it is clear in the gita

Answer (score 4):

Katha Upanishad 1:1:6 has a similar meaning.

> अनुपश्य यथा पूर्वे प्रतिपश्य तथापरे । सस्यमिव मर्त्य: पच्यते सस्यमिवाजायते पुन: ॥६॥

> 1-I-6. Think how your ancestors behaved; behold how others now behave. **Like corn man decays, and like corn he is born again.**

It is saying that man is like corn which take birth, grows and decays (die).

Taittaraiya Upanishad also has a similar Verse.

> भृगुर्वै वारुणिः । वरुणं पितरमुपससार । अधीहि भगवो ब्रह्मेति । तस्मा एतत्प्रोवाच । अन्नं प्राणं चक्षुः श्रोत्रं मनो वाचमिति । तꣳहोवाच । यतो वा इमानि भूतानि जायन्ते । येन जातानि जीवन्ति । यत्प्रयन्त्यभिसंविशन्ति । तद्विजिज्ञासस्व । तद्ब्रह्मेति । स तपोऽतप्यत । स तपस्तप्त्वा ॥१॥

> III-i-1: Bhrigu, the well-known son of Varuna, approached his father Varuna with the (formal) request, "O, revered sir, teach me Brahman". To him he (Varuna) said this: "Food, vital force, eye, ear, mind, speech - (these are the aids to knowledge of Brahman)". To him he (Varuna) said: "Crave to know that from which all **these beings take birth, that by which they live after being born, that towards which they move and into which they merge**. That is Brahman". He practiced concentration. He, having practiced concentration,